# Getting related data in a list

Tags: database, performance

I would like to print a list of items from a database table, and together with each one, a little list (10 items max) of related subitems.

For example, I have these 2 tables:

```
ITEMS

id: integer
name: string


SUBITEMS

id: integer
name: string
item_id: integer
```

So, an item can have many subitems.

I would like to print something like this:

```
Item 1
this item has: subitem 1, subitem 2, subitem 3

Item 2
this item has: subitem 4, subitem 5, subitem 6

Item 3
this item has: subitem 2, subitem 4, subitem 7
```

How could I get this with performance in mind? As I said, each item can have many subitems, but I'll be showing a maximum of 10.

If I make a select with a join, I think it could stress too much the database when there is a pagination of, for example, 25 items per page, and 100 users querying. So, I think this would not be a good solution.

I have thought about a workaround, something dirty: adding a new field to the ITEMS table, named subitems_summary (of type text), and each time a subitem is assigned to an item, I make the select to join the two tables, and store there the results, so I can format the data from that field later on. For example, in the listing above, the subitems_summary field for Item 3 would be: "subitem 2; subitem 4; subitem 7".

What do you think?

Comment: Consider what your "dirty workaround" not only does for the performance of select but also inserts, updates, and deletes for individual sub items.

Comment: I would use `select *` and just iterate over the resultset and print the non-null values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm not getting more answers I'll post my opinion.

As Oleksi says, the DBMS is good enough to run joined queries. This can be true with a low quantity of visitors. But keeping an eye on scaling, this would not be an optimized way to do complex things.

I think there are interesting techniques that I would love to read, but I'm more towards optimizing queries from the start, at least a little. In my opinion it's not a good idea to use joins deliberately. In professional sites it's better to duplicate fields just for that reason.

Anyway, to achieve what I was asking, I would do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11301759/267705

Answer (score 0):

Unless your table of items is truly massive, a join will do this sufficiently fast enough. It's the cleanest solution, so you should implement that first. Then you can measure performance and see if it is really too slow. I think you'll find that it'll be fast enough. If not, you can also try to add an index to the columns that get used a lot in the queries you make. This will give the DBMS more powerful optimization options that it may choose to make.

Your DBMS is usually very very good at optimizing queries like these, so you should see how fast it can make the query first, before getting into custom optimizations.

Comment: Well, I think that what I need cannot be get unless I use subqueries. And this is even more demanding.