# How can I get a list with sublists using one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I would like to print a list of items from a database table, and together with each one, a little list (10 items max) of related subitems.

For example, I have these 2 tables:

```
ITEMS

id: integer
name: string


SUBITEMS

id: integer
name: string
item_id: integer
```

So, an item can have many subitems.

I would like to print something like this:

```
Item 1
this item has: subitem 1, subitem 2, subitem 3

Item 2
this item has: subitem 4, subitem 5, subitem 6

Item 3
this item has: subitem 2, subitem 4, subitem 7
```

How can this be done in SQL? Is this even possible?

Comment: Please specify which SQL database system you are using.

Comment: I'm using SQLite for development, but I'll be using MySQL in production.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's MySQL then

```
select i.*, group_concat(si.name) as subitems
from items i
left join subitems si on si.item_id = i.id
group by i.id
```

Comment: Is there any way to limit subitems list to 10?

Comment: It's limited by **group_concat_max_len** which is a global variable and if I am not wrong it should be 1024 bytes long by default.

Comment: Ok, so it could be modified running this before the query: SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=4096

Comment: A better way to limit the subitems list would be by using the substring_index on the group_concat. I'm writting a new answer to wrap it all, although I'm marking yours as the final answer.

Comment: Indeed, SUBSTRING_INDEX could be used for limiting to 10 subitems.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need it to print this out straight from SQL?

The typical query would look like

```
SELECT i.item_id,si,item_id FROM Items i
         INNER JOIN Subitems si on i.item_id = si.item_id
         ORDER BY i.item_id
```

You would typically use your application layer to do the printing, though.  If you *really* needed to have rows like you've shown, you could do something with a cursor, but a direct query is going to look very funky if you want that exact  output.

Check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat for MySQL

SQLite appears to support a similar operation:  http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html

Comment: Isn't it possible to get 3 rows in total? First would be: "Item 1", "subitem 1", "subitem 2", "subitem 3", or similar.

Comment: This is possible in MSSQL with CROSS APPLY, but I don't think MySQL has this yet

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Parahat we have a clear answer on how to do it:

```
SELECT i.name, GROUP_CONCAT(si.name) AS subitems
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN subitems si ON si.item_id = i.id
GROUP BY i.id
```

This way we have an unlimited list of subitems, that is truncated by the global variable group_concat_max_len.

But there is a better way to limit that to the initial maximum of 10 of my question:

```
SELECT i.name,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(si.name), ', ', 10) AS subitems
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN subitems si ON si.item_id = i.id
GROUP BY i.id
```

This only works on MySQL though.

Answer (score -1):

you need to use the group by clause:

you would need

```
select * from tblsubitems
          group by(item_id);
```

more info for [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#resultset), [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)